# How can I type the return value of a function of type Set with a class key

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make a function that returns a Set of class's keys. But I can't find what type of definition it should be.

```
class Bot {
  public no01: number;
  public no02: number;

  constructor(no01: number, no02: number) {
    this.no01 = no01;
    this.no02 = no02;
  }
}

function getSet(): Set<keyof Bot> {
  return new Set(["no01"]);
}
```

I and up getting this error:

```
"Type 'Set<string>' is not assignable to type 'Set<keyof Bot>'.
 Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof Bot'."
```

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrGxom) work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try a more verbose but still type-checked way:

```
class Bot {
  public no01: number;
  public no02: number;
}

function getSet(): Set<keyof Bot> {
  const values: (keyof Bot)[] = ["no01"];
  // const wrongValues: (keyof Bot)[] = ["no03"]; // will be an error here
  return new Set(values);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's perfect for me!